# Define matrices in an array element C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, 4d

I have written some c++ code that receives a Matrix as input and now I want to create a 2D array with matrices in each element so that I can send the individual matrices to the function.

typedef vector< vector > Matrix;
double a[2][2] = Matrix(2, vector(2));

so that each element of a is a 2x2 Matrix.

The reason I don't want to just create a 4D array with vectors is that I want to keep all of the original functions that I have already created with matrices as input.

Any way this is possible?

Here is a simple example code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
typedef vector< vector > Matrix;

void test2D_array(int l, int m, Matrix &a, Matrix &b) {
        int R = l - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++) {
            b[l - 1][i] = a[l][i];
            b[l - 2][i] = (l - 1) * a[l - 1][i];
            for (int k = R-1; k > 0; k--) {
                b[k - 1][i] = b[k + 1][i] + a[k][i];
            }
        }
    }


int main(void) {
    
    Matrix a(2, vector<double>(2));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    Matrix b(2, vector<double>(2));
    
    test2D_array(2, 2, a, b);
    
    // What I want to accomplish...
    // Matrix a[2][2] = Matrix((2, vector<double>(2)); i.e. 4D array with each element a 2x2 matrix
    // for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    //  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    //      test2D_array(2, 2, a[i][j], b);
    //  }
    //}
    //
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not know what is a `Matrix` here, but provided it is both default constructible and copyable, you can easily build and use a vector of vectors of matrices: `std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>>`.

Comment: It's very much possible if you define a Matrix class with the required functionality and moreover `a` should be of type Matrix as well.

Comment: Matrix is: typedef vector< vector<double> > Matrix; Would that still work?
I'm not sure I know how I would go about creating a matrix class.

Comment: "I have written some c++ code that receives a Matrix as input" Please show a [mre] of that. The data structures are important for answring the rest of your question.

Comment: I have updated witha simple example code of what I want to accomplish.